# How to write AngularJS code to Angular 9?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am struggling to convert an Angular JS code to Angular 9. This code runs very well with Angular JS. Particularly I am struggling with passing an array in ngModel.

**Edit**
Thank you for all your responses. However when I run my controller code, the code give an error.

AngularJS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      Vendor Name: <input type="text"> <br> <br> Vendor Details: <textarea> </textarea> <br> <br>
      <button ng-click="myFunc()">Click to enter Observations</button>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="observation in observations track by $index">
      <br> <br>
      <form>
        Detailed Observation <input type="text" ng-model="observations[$index]">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="nextObservation($index)" ng-if="$last"> Next Observation </button>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="finish()" ng-if="$last"> Finish </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.observations = [];

      $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.observations.push('');
      }
      $scope.nextObservation = function($index) {
        $scope.observations[$index]
        if ($scope.observations[$index]) {
          $scope.observations.push('');
        }
      }
      $scope.finish = function() {
        console.log($scope.observations);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got a solution from a couple of people. I coded with the help of all the responses that I received. The final code was made without the help of reactive forms.

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  Vendor Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Vendor Name" />
  <br> <br>
  Vendor Details: <textarea> </textarea> <br> <br>
  <button (click)="addItem()">Click to enter Observations</button>
  <br><br>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let observation of observations; let i=index; last as isLast; trackBy:trackByFn">
  <div>
    Detailed Observation {{i+1}}: <input type= "text" placeholder="Observation name" [(ngModel)]= "observations[i]">
    <button type="submit" (click)="nextObservation(i)" *ngIf="isLast"> Next Observation </button>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

observations=[];

  addItem()
  {
    this.observations.push('');
  }

  nextObservation(i)
  {
   if (this.observations[i])
    {
      this.observations.push('');
    }
  }

  trackByFn(index: any, item: any) {
   return index;
}
}
```

Thank you for all your responses.

Comment: What is your dataset for ```observations``` ? And what you have tried so far in Angular 9?

Comment: Again, no shortage of docs on the subject: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: So this is a small part of my code. Where I am actually stuck is changing
 ng-model="observation[$index]"

Comment: Observations will be taken as input from a text area.

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, Hope this helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-z6hrap

Comment: @ManirajMurugan I have edited my question. Please help me with that.

Comment: "the code give an error" -> what error ? can you paste the stack trace ?

Comment: @Célia [link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m3wuee

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, You need to use angular reactive form and here is the modified stackblitz...     https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-nycktc

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, Reactive form reference: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and ```ngForOf``` with trackby reference: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables ..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan The "Next Observation" Button does not seem to be working.

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, What is the logic for Next Observation? What actually needs to happen when you click on that? Because in your Angular Js project also I don't see any action happening on click of the button..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan If we add details in the text box of "Detailed observation". The "Next Observation" button becomes active. Which helps you go to the next form.

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, Still unclear.. Can you make the same thing working in Angular Js application? You can also edit the code here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/jOWmMQa and it is your angular js one and send me the modified one with your expected result..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan The code which is currently in codepen works perfectly fine.
The form works like like this Enter Vendor Name-> Enter Vendor Details-> Click "Click to enter observation"-> Enter the detailed observation -> Click " Next Observation" -> Another Form generates

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, Also the button disable if the detail observation text box is empty has been made and the link for the same here https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-tmmmpp  .. Hope this is all you want..

Comment: @DharnaKhandelwal, Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let observation of observations; index as i; last as isLast">
  <br> <br>
  <form>
    Detailed Observation <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="observations[i]">
    <button type="submit" (click)="nextObservation(i)" *ngIf="isLast"> Next Observation </button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="finish()" *ngIf="isLast"> Finish </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I have updated my question. Please help me, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

**in component.ts file inside class**

```
  observations: string[] = [];

  ngOninit() {
    this.observations.push('');
  }

  nextObservation($index) {
    this.observations[$index]
    if (this.observations[$index]) {
      this.observations.push('');
    }
  }

  finish() {
    console.log(this.observations);
  }
```